# How to align a text of cell in a table to center using python-docx?

Tags: python-docx

I searched a lot but i am not able to get through it. If anybody has experience of `python-docx` can help be in few thing as below.

My code as under:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Cm, Inches
from docx.enum.table import WD_TABLE_ALIGNMENT
from docx.enum.table import WD_ALIGN_VERTICAL
from docx.enum.section import WD_ORIENT
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH

chart = Document()

style = chart.styles['Normal']
font = style.font

from docx.shared import Pt
font.size = Pt(12)
font.underline = False

# Table Starts
print("Table Making Starts..")
table = chart.add_table(rows=1, cols=2, style='Table Grid')

# Adding Table Heading Text
cell0 = table.cell(0, 0)
cell0.vertical_alignment = WD_ALIGN_VERTICAL.CENTER
cell0.bold = True
cell0.text = "Column1"

cell1 = table.cell(0, 1)
cell1.bold = True
cell1.text = "Column2"
cell1.vertical_alignment = WD_ALIGN_VERTICAL.CENTER

chart.save('./test7.docx')
```

But the problem is that it is not doing formatting to align the text to center.

My Code Output:

[image]

Expected Output:
[image]

Comment: You must center each individual paragraph. Vertical alignment is on the cell, but horizontal alignment is on each paragraph and you can, for example, have a centered, left, and right aligned paragraph all in the same cell.

Comment: but is there any function to use to make cell text at center? is the case of paragraph and cell value are different case

Comment: If possible can you refer some solution or update this above code

Comment: The documentation for `python-docx` is here: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html and in particular, the API for a paragraph object is described here: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#paragraph-objects. This page gives an example how to use it: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/enum/WdAlignParagraph.html#wdparagraphalignment